# How to get value of a cell in google sheet set as variable in HTML?

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I am trying to create menu in google sheet to upload multiple files from my computer to google drive. I found this great snippet:

```
function openAttachmentDialog() {
 var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('forms');
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
 .showModalDialog(html, 'Upload File');
}
function createFolder(parentFolderId, folderName) {
    try {
        var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId);
        var folders = parentFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);
        var folder;
        if (folders.hasNext()) {
            folder = folders.next();
        } else {
            folder = parentFolder.createFolder(folderName);
        }
        return {
            'folderId' : folder.getId()
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return {
            'error' : e.toString()
        }
    }
}

function uploadFile(base64Data, fileName, folderId) {
    try {
        var splitBase = base64Data.split(','), type = splitBase[0].split(';')[0]
                .replace('data:', '');
        var byteCharacters = Utilities.base64Decode(splitBase[1]);
        var ss = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, type);
        ss.setName(fileName);

        var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
        var files = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);
        var file;
        while (files.hasNext()) {
            // delete existing files with the same name.
            file = files.next();
            folder.removeFile(file);
        }
        file = folder.createFile(ss);
        return {
            'folderId' : folderId,
            'fileName' : file.getName()
        };
    } catch (e) {
        return {
            'error' : e.toString()
        };
    }
}
```

And this is HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="uploaderForm">
        <label for="uploaderForm">Upload multiple Files</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="applicantName" id="applicantName"
                placeholder="Title of quiz">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="applicantEmail" id="applicantEmail"
                placeholder="Note">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="file" name="filesToUpload" id="filesToUpload" multiple>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="uploadFiles()">
        </div>
    </form>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script>
        var rootFolderId = 'My IdFolder';
        var numUploads = {};
        numUploads.done = 0;
        numUploads.total = 0;
        // Upload the files into a folder in drive
        // This is set to send them all to one folder (specificed in the .gs file)
        function uploadFiles() {
            var allFiles = document.getElementById('filesToUpload').files;
            var applicantName = document.getElementById('applicantName').value;
            if (!applicantName) {
                window.alert('Missing applicant name!');
            }
            var applicantEmail = document.getElementById('applicantEmail').value;
            if (!applicantEmail) {
                window.alert('Missing applicant email!');
            }
            var folderName = applicantName + ' ' + applicantEmail;
            if (allFiles.length == 0) {
                window.alert('No file selected!');
            } else {
                numUploads.total = allFiles.length;
                google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(r) {
                    // send files after the folder is created...
                    for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
                        // Send each file at a time
                        uploadFile(allFiles[i], r.folderId);
                    }
                }).createFolder(rootFolderId, folderName);
            }
        }
        function uploadFile(file, folderId) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var content = reader.result;
                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'uploading '
                        + file.name + '...';
                //window.alert('uploading ' + file.name + '...');               
                google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onFileUploaded)
                        .uploadFile(content, file.name, folderId);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
        function onFileUploaded(r) {
            numUploads.done++;
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'uploaded '
                    + r.fileName + ' (' + numUploads.done + '/'
                    + numUploads.total + ' files).';
            if (numUploads.done == numUploads.total) {
                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'All of the '
                        + numUploads.total + ' files are uploaded';
                numUploads.done = 0;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course this is a great product for me. However, I want to replace 'My IdFolder' with a variable taken from google sheet, for example:

```
var rootFolderId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('tests').getRange('AH1').getValue();
```

I really don't know how. I need help!

Comment: Where did you find it? https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [HTML Templating](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) with the use of [Scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets)

For this you will need to create the HTML output as below:

```js
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); //get active spreadsheet
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('tests'); //get the sheet
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); //get spreadsheet ui
  var valFromSheet = sh.getRange('AH1').getValue(); //get value to display in html
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('forms'); //create the temlpate
  html.myIdFolder = valFromSheet; //specify the value for scriptlet
  var output = html.evaluate(); //evaluate the template
  var show = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(output) //create the output from template
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setWidth(400) //options
  .setHeight(130); //options
  ui.showModalDialog(show, 'Upload File'); //show the html!
```

Then in the html, to show the value you need to insert the scriptlet `<?= myIdFolder ?>` for your `var`

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed help! Did you mean you inserted a scriptlet for var like this: <? var rootFolderId = myIdFolder; ?> . I did and it still doesn't work!

Comment: Amazing, it finally worked. Thank you very much! I've set `var rootFolderId = <?=myIdFolder?>;`

Comment: Yes, like the above.  The semi-colon needs to go at the end of the line in JS to terminate the statement.